# DTN (Delay Tolerant Networking) on Android

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth, dtn

Has there been an implementation of the DTN stack on Android with the Bluetooth Convergence Layer?

I have looked at existing implementations like Bytewalla, but they support only TCP as of now. I understand that the Bytewalla implementation can be extended to support Bluetooth, but did not want to re-invent the wheel if someone else has done it already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my own **Java Implementation of Bundling protocol** running on `LTP` **(LickLider Transmission Protocol)** that was design and implemented by my friend and Colleague.

`LTP` could run on `WiFi` as well as `BlueTooth`.

You may want to check that out.

[1] http://irg.cs.ohiou.edu/ocp/index.html

Note : the Impl is a bit old now. There are lot of changes to the BP protocol as well (it was a draft then, now its a standard track RFC). so you may want to do some exploration.

Comment: Nice, stumbled upon this after all this while.